# Default Value for Map in Collectors.toMap()

Tags: java, collections, java-8, java-stream

Need to convert `List<Object>` to `Map<String,Long>` with Long value as zero using `Collectors.toMap()`.

Here Object refers to my own defined java class.

```
List<Test> list = new ArrayList<Test>(); list.add(X); list.add(Y);
Map<String,Long> map = list.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(Test:getName,XXXX)));
```

My Expected Output:

```
{"x",0},{"Y",0}
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use lambda expression for the value:

```
Map<String, Long> map = list.stream()
                           .collect(Collectors.toMap(Test:getName,x -> 0L,(a,b)->a));
```

You can also use `BigDecimal` constant

```
Map<String, Long> map = list.stream()
                           .collect(Collectors.toMap(Test:getName,x -> BigDecimal.ZERO.longValue(),(a,b)->a));
```

Comment: I would like to suggest you to add `mergeFunction` inside `toMap()` , It will make the collection more robust.  `list.stream()
                           .collect(Collectors.toMap(Test:getName,x -> 0L,(a,b)->a));`